# Non-stock Android SQLite library?

Tags: android, open-source, library, sqlite

For [some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764943/android-deletes-corrupt-sqlite-files-automatically) and others, I want to avoid Android's official SQLite implementation.

Requirements:

- SQLite format
- Has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
- The most implemented operations the better
- Basic WHERE, with indexes
- Indexes are updated
- Open Source

Note: I recently ported [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) to Android, and I just saw the website of [SQLdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sqldroid/) (not sure what it does). I am surprised I can't find any fork of Android's SQLite, that could be acceptable as well.

Comment: *TitaniumBackup* brings its own SQLite library. Not sure whether it's a fork or just a "specific version", but you might contact Joël and ask him.